# R: Filling a matrix with binary values depending on the content of other data frames

Tags: r

I have two data frames like the ones pasted below:

df1:

```
v   a
w   b
x   c
y   d
z   e
```

df2:

```
v   A
v   C
w   A
x   B
y   C
z   C
z   B
```

As you can see the values v-z link the two data frames.

I have set up a third data frame like this:

df3:

```
    A   B   C
a   NA  NA  NA
b   NA  NA  NA
c   NA  NA  NA
d   NA  NA  NA
e   NA  NA  NA
```

And I want to fill it with 0s and 1s, like this:

df3:

```
    A   B   C
a   1   0   1
b   1   0   0
c   0   1   0
d   0   0   1
e   0   1   1
```

Basically, if we take the first line of df1 as an example, we can see that "a" corresponds to "v". In df2, we can see that "v" corresponds to both "A" and "C", so in df3, in the "a" row, there will be a "1" in the "A" and "C" column.

Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

I thought about applying a function over df3, looking up the row and column names of each element and see if they are joined in df1 and df2, but I am not sure how to do that.

I hope I explained this clearly enough, please don't hesitate to tell me if it is not clear, I will try to improve my explanation. I also apologize for the clumsy title, I don't know how these manipulations are called.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
library(dplyr)
full_join(df1, df2, by=c("V1"="V1")) %>% 
  select(V2.x, V2.y) %>%
  table()

    V2.y
V2.x A B C
   a 1 0 1
   b 1 0 0
   c 0 1 0
   d 0 0 1
   e 0 1 1
```

#### Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("v", "w", "x", "y", "z"), V2 = c("a", "b", 
"c", "d", "e")), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

df2 <- structure(list(V1 = c("v", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "z"), V2 = c("A", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "C", "B")), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Pretty neat! Thank you

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do further manipulations on the resulting table, but it does not behave like a normal data frame, even when using as.data.frame. How can I convert it to a normal data frame? For example, I am trying to remove the row.names and use them as the first column, using (df3test <- setDT(as.data.frame(df3), keep.rownames = TRUE)[]). But this gives me a data frame with only one column of binary data (freq), instead of the three columns that we got. Thank you!

Comment: Use `as.data.frame.matrix`.

Answer (score 1):

One base R option is using `merge`. We `merge` the `df1` and `df2` by common column `V1` and then find the frequency using `table`.

```
m <- merge(df1, df2, by = "V1", all.x = TRUE)
table(m$V2.x, m$V2.y)

#   A B C
# a 1 0 1
# b 1 0 0
# c 0 1 0
# d 0 0 1
# e 0 1 1
```

where `m` after merging comes out to be:

```
  V1 V2.x V2.y
1  v    a    A
2  v    a    C
3  w    b    A
4  x    c    B
5  y    d    C
6  z    e    C
7  z    e    B
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you want `table`, which is what the other answers have already arrived at, but they proposed approaching the problem with `merge` (or its "tidyverse" variant, `full_join`).

However, a more efficient approach would be to simply use `match` or `factor` and then `table`. Both of the following would also give you the output you're expecting.

```
# match -- probably slightly faster than factor
table(df1$V2[match(df2$V1, df1$V1)], df2$V2)

# factor -- a little bit easier to read
table(factor(df2$V1, df1$V1, df1$V2), df2$V2)
```